# Disable autohide controls in chrome video element

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

I need to keep the controls always visible in a chrome video element

```
<video src="video.mp4" controls></video>
```

Actually they are auto-hidden after few milliseconds

How to disable that behaviour making them always visible?

Answer (score 7):

Finally I figured it out... Using CSS pseudo selectors

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    display: flex !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```